# insertion creates duplicate with same data

Tags: mysql, php

I am using MySQL with PHP. I fetch data from a third party using SOAP.

I have an issue with duplicate insertion of data. This occurs once or twice a day.

Say there are 10 records ready to enter into the system. I create a loop to insert the records one by one. Each has a reference number which should be unique. In my case it is not. The code looks like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($Result['return']);$i++)
{

//Here function is working and this function check the duplication

//here in function record are inserted 
//In this function a query exists that checks the existing maximum record
//then associates with a new one
//Query that fetches the max ref Number
 SELECT MAX(distNumber)+1 as max_ref FROM orders
//then insert statement of an orders 

}
```

The system inserts duplicate records and `distNumber` is the same for all duplicated orders.

My overall issue is my MAX query worked one time and other insertion query runs multiple times. That is why the system inserted the same order twice and `distNumber` is the same for both.

I want to save my system from duplication of records at run time.

Comment: Why don't you make a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column instead using `MAX()+1`? Btw, can you please add your `SHOW CREATE TABLE table;` to your question?